# Why is my React app is displaying a blank page?

Tags: reactjs

When running "yarn start" and trying to deploy the app, nothing as simple as "Home" will render on the screen. I have tried changing react versions, toast versions, react router versions etc, and nothing has worked. Please let me know if you notice anything. Also there are currently no console errors

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import  {
  Route, 
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Components/Home/home";
import Profile from "./Components/Profile/profile";
import Sidepanel from "./Components/SidePanel/sidepanel";
import Signin from "./Components/Signin/signin";
import Signup from "./Components/Signup/signup";
import {toast, ToastContainer} from 'react-toastify';

class App extends Component {
  showToast = (type, message)=> {
    switch(type) {
      case 0:
        toast.warning(message)
        break;
      case 1: 
        toast.success(message)
        default: 
          break;
    }
  } 
  render() {
    return(
      <Router>
        <ToastContainer
        autoClose="2000"
        hideProgressBar= {true}
        position= {toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER}
        />
        <Routes>
          <Route 
          exact
          path="/"
          render= {props => <Home {...props}/>}
          />
          <Route 
          path="/signin"
          render= {props => <Signin showToast={this.showToast}{...props}/>}
          />
          <Route 
          path="/signup"
          render= {props => <Signup showToast={this.showToast}{...props}/>}
          />
          <Route 
          path="/profile"
          render= {props => <Profile showToast={this.showToast}{...props}/>}
          />
          <Route 
          path="/chat"
          render= {props => <Sidepanel showToast={this.showToast}{...props}/>}
          />

        </Routes>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React from "react";

class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Home</h1>
            </div>
        );
    };
};
export default Home;
```

Comment: Is `ToastContainer` allowed under `Router`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to next sub-routes as children. This is taken almost verbatim from the React Router examples:

```js
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />

            <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Layout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/nothing-here">Nothing Here</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <hr />

      {/* An <Outlet> renders whatever child route is currently active,
          so you can think about this <Outlet> as a placeholder for
          the child routes we defined above. */}
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see in this example, these is your route to `/`, and within that route is another route with the `index` value set. This is what will be used as the index